# Reading & Writing to textfile android

Tags: android, filereader, file-writing

I'm attempting to use a simple textfile as a basis for storing some persistent data, and all solutions that I've seen online haven't been working for me.

Placing the textfile within the assets doesn't allow runtime manipulation, but allowed me to read from the file.

Allowing android to create the file shown as the following:

```
        OutputStream os = openFileOutput("Persistant.txt", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os));
        bw.write("data");
        bw.newLine();
```

However when attempting to read from this file later on the following is returned:
        /Persistant.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

```
     BufferedReader in
                = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Persistant.txt"));
```

Therefore, can anyone provide assistance as to where to store the textfile, or the issue itself?

Thanks

Comment: This file goes to data folder of application named as package of app

Comment: what is opposite to "Output" ?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html -- This link have your answer.

Comment: Why don't you use a database?

Comment: Its just simple stuff storing text strings, thought a database was alot of extra work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the openFileOutput() method of your Context to create a file in your app's private storage:

```
OutputStream os = openFileOutput("Persistant.txt", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
```

So you should use the openFileInput() method to read it:

```
 BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                      new InputStreamReader(openFileInput("Persistant.txt")));
```

Otherwise, if you really want to use the File constructor, you will first have to obtain the folder name:

```
 BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                      new FileReader(new File(getFilesDir(),"Persistant.txt")));
```

When you do not do this, you try to open the file from your program's current working directory which is likely the root directory of the device - not where you stored your file, and not a place where you would be allowed to write anything.

Answer (score -2):

have you declared permission to read and write to external storage in manifest.xml..? like,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: No. These permissions are for the external storage, not the internal.